# Generating pdf in Laravelu

Tags: laravel-5, pdf-generation

In Laravel I want generating pdf with data about items and company, my relations:
Invoice.php

```
    class Invoice extends Model
    {
       public function company() {
          return $this->belongsTo('App\Company');
        }

        public function items() {
          return $this->belongsToMany('App\Item', 'invoice_items', 'invoice_id', 'item_id')
            ->withPivot('quantity');
      }
}
```

---

PdfController.php

```
 public function pdfviewInvoice(Request $request)
    {
        $invoices = DB::table("invoices")->get();
        view()->share('invoices', $invoices);

        if ($request->has('download')) {

            $company = Company::all();
            $items = Item::all();
            $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.pdfviewInvoice', compact('company', 'items'));

            return $pdf->download('pdfviewInvoice.pdf');
        }

        return view('pdfviewInvoice');
    }
```

---

pdfviewInvoice.blade.php

```
  @foreach($invoices as $key => $invoice)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ ++$key }}</td>
                <td>{{ $invoice->number }}</td>
                <td>{{ $invoice->status }}</td>
                <td>{{ $invoice->place_issue }}</td>
                <td>{{ $invoice->date_issue }}</td>
                <td>{{ $invoice->date_payment }}</td>
                <td>{{ $invoice->company->name }}</td>
                <td>
                    <table class="table text-center">
                        <td class="text-center">Item</td>
                        <td class="text-center">Unit</td>
                        <td class="text-center">Price</td>
                        <td class="text-center">VAT</td>
                        <td class="text-center">Quantity</td>
                        @foreach($invoice->items as $item)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ $item->name }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $item->unit }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $item->price_net }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $item->vat->value."%"}}</td>
                                <td>{{ $item->pivot->quantity }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
```

And when I want to display this get an error
"Undefined property: stdClass::$items (View: C:\praca_inzynierska-master\resources\views\pdf\pdfviewInvoice.blade.php)"

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is there anything present in `$invoice->items`? Looks like its empty or not defined at all

Comment: I have relationships in the Invoice model: 
public function items() {
          return $this->belongsToMany('App\Item', 'invoice_items', 'invoice_id', 'item_id')->withPivot('quantity');
      }

Comment: and I have     
$company = Company::all();
$items = Item::all();
but it really looks like it's empty but I do not know why :(

Comment: I think it is more a relationship problem instead of anything with the pdf generation. I suggest you take a good look on https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships if everything is set up correctly it should work.